# How to install php7 without '--enable-debug' flag?

Tags: php, xdebug

Do You know how to compile php7 in debian without set `--enable-debug` flag?
I think I have to do it because when I install `xdebug` it says that: `_zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper` is not defined. I find on the internet that this may be because my php7 `--enable-debug` flag set.

Comment: Is there some special reason you're compiling your own? There's repositories with precompiled installs and none of them come with that flag enabled

Comment: I have used vagrant debian box with precompiled php7. Now I'am changing it to normal debian distro. But don't understand why, even in debug mode, there is something missing. Why is there debug mode for if it doesn't have got everything what is needed ? :/